# how to check if there is data for the last 2 days in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to check if users submit their data for the last 2 days.  I have 2 fields in my table: USERID AND DATE_SUBMITTED.  I do have data for the last 2 days in my table but my query is not returning any data.  what am i doing wrong here:

```
select distinct [UserID], DT_Submitted 
from myTable 
where [UserID] = 'Joe'
  and DT_Submitted = (select CAST(FLOOR( CAST( GETDATE()-1 AS FLOAT ) )AS DATETIME))
  and DT_Submitted = (select CAST(FLOOR( CAST( GETDATE()-2 AS FLOAT ) )AS DATETIME))
```

thanks

Comment: Why not just: `select distinct [UserID], DT_Submitted from  myTable where [UserID] = 'Joe' AND DT_Submitted >= dateadd(day, -2, getdate())` ?

Comment: thanks but the reason is we want the query to return some data only if user submitted for both days.  I don't want to return anything if we find data for one day only.  It has to be 2 days of data or no data.  How can i do that?

Comment: Well.. that explains why your query isn't returning anything. Since it can only apply the WHERE clause to one record at a time, and a single record can not have two dates in the same field.

Comment: Also, why are you casting as `FLOAT` (instead of as `DATE`)? And please be careful about [shorthand like -1](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx) - explicit `DATEADD` is better.

Comment: Your code is not working because the where clause only analyzes applies to one row. So your where clause is looking at a specific submission date and checking if it is the same as yesterday's date and the same as today's date which of course is impossible. Thus no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previous people have answered but I believe they are working too hard and probably using more resources with multiple joins and distincs, etc... Try this out.

```
SELECT  UserID,
        DT_Submitted INTO myTable
FROM
(
    --Submitted both days
    SELECT 'Joe' UserID,DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()) DT_Submitted
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Joe' UserID,DATEADD(DAY,-2,GETDATE()) DT_Submitted
    UNION ALL
    --Submitted one day
    SELECT 'Bob',DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()) DT_Submitted
    UNION ALL
    --Submitted 5 days ago
    SELECT 'Helen',DATEADD(DAY,-5,GETDATE()) DT_Submitted
) A

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT  UserID,
            --All this does is count the submissions in the past two days and then adds them up
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN CAST(DT_submitted AS DATE) =  DATEADD(DAY,-1,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) THEN 1
                    WHEN CAST(DT_submitted AS DATE) =  DATEADD(DAY,-2,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) THEN 1
                    ELSE 0          
                END) AS submissions 
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY UserID
) A
WHERE submissions = 2
```

**Results:**

```
UserID submissions
------ -----------
Joe    2
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to find records where the USERID submitted yesterday AND the day before yesterday. You will need something like:

```
SELECT
    userID,
    Dt_Submitted
FROM
    myTable
WHERE
    userid = 'Joe' AND
    userid IN (SELECT distinct userid FROM myTable Where Dt_Submitted = dateadd(day, -2, getdate())) AND
    userid IN (SELECT distinct userid FROM myTable Where Dt_Submitted = dateadd(day, -1, getdate()))
```

If you have a newer version of SQL Server using Window functions:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            userID,
            Dt_Submitted, 
            CASE 
                WHEN
                    MAX(Dt_Submitted) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY dt_submitted ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) = dateAdd(day, -1, dt_submitted) ORDER
                    MIN(Dt_Submitted) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY dt_submitted ROWS UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) = dateAdd(day, +1, dt_submitted)
                THEN 'X' as keeptest

        FROM
            myTable
        WHERE
            userid = 'Joe' AND
    )sub
WHERE keeptest = 'X'
```

Or removing records using a JOIN (very similar to the first):

```
SELECT
    t1.userID,
    t1.Dt_Submitted
FROM
    myTable t1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT distinct userid, dt_submitted FROM myTable Where Dt_Submitted = dateadd(day, -2, getdate())) t2 ON
        t1.userid = t2.userid
        AND t1.dt_submitted = t2.dt_submitted
    INNER JOIN (SELECT distinct userid,dt_submitted FROM myTable Where Dt_Submitted = dateadd(day, -1, getdate())) t3 ON
        t1.userid = t3.userid
        AND t1.dt_submitted = t3.dt_submitted
WHERE
    t1.userid = 'Joe'
```